# Is there any datset which has human judgement scores between 2 english senctences only?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dataset

I am trying to propose an evaluation metric in NLP and I need to compare it with other baseline metric such as Bleu scores.

I need a dataset which has 2 english sentences (say same image being described by 2 different persons) and along with that a human judgement score on the quality of those sentences.

Ay inputs will be very much appreciated. I'm willing to calculate pearson correlation coeff between blue score and human judgement score; and between proposed metric and human judgement score to see which is giving a higher correlation coeff.

Could you specify the direct link to download such txt/ csv file if there exists one.

I found wmt metrics dataset that is a translation between different langauges. I am looking for 2 english sentences only along with a human judgement score

Comment: Your requirements are strange, because it's unusual to devise a metric unrelated to any task. Because of this you want to compare your metric vs. BLEU, but afaik BLEU is not used anymore as a sole evaluation metric. Also it's not clear what your metric is supposed to compare: it's probably a lexical similarity measure like BLEU? Is it supposed to take into account semantics, like e.g. TFIDF? Would it be able to measure the style of the text, as for authorship identification? (this task has two texts as input, but the gold is a binary variable).

Comment: hello sir, thanks for you comment. You are partially correct that BLEU is not used solely however as per my limited knowledge and whatever I have learnt so far, there are many metrics used in combination to evaluate results. Sir, my requirements might sound strange to you and I see you have a very rich experience in the research community. I am just a beginner as compared to you. However, I am willing to learn much and my requirement infact is very specific. All I wanted to know is about a dataset that gives me human judgement score between 2 sentences. Would really appreciate your suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the paraphrasing task meets your requirements, you could check [these datasets](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/paraphrase-data-sets). There are similar tasks possibly relevant as well: paraphrase generation, simplification. If this doesn't work you could browse the tasks listed [here](https://nlpprogress.com/) and try to find one.